# How to iterate through a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration, output

```py
def topping_type_and_num(amount_of_toppings, count, toppings_dict):
    toppings_chosen = {}
    for a in range (int(amount_of_toppings)):
        list_of_toppings()
        topping_chosen = input("\nWhich topping would you like?: ")
        topping_selected = topping_chosen
        toppings_chosen["topping_" + str(a + 1)] = topping_selected
        toppings_dict.update({"Pizza_" + str(count): toppings_chosen})
    print(topping_chosen)
    print(toppings_dict)
    for i, j in toppings_dict.items():
        print(i, ' : ', j)
```

Is it possible to make my output look good on a recipt?
Such as:

```
Pizza_0: topping_1 : 1, topping_2 : 2, topping_3 : 3, topping4: 4
```

Maybe even have the toppings indented and a line below the pizza?
I would like to have as little : ' and , as possible in my output

Comment: Of course it is possible.  You just have to do it.  THIS function handles a single pizza.  If you want to have multiple pizza on a single receipt, then you can't do the printing in this function.  And printing from a nested dictionary just means nested `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

```py
toppings_dict = {
    'Pizza_0': {
        'topping_1': '1',
        'topping_2': '2',
        'topping_3': '3',
        'topping_4': '4'
        }
    }

for i, j in toppings_dict.items():
    tops = ''.join(f'\n  {k} {v}' for k, v in j.items())
    print(i, tops)
```

output:

```
Pizza_0 
  topping_1 1
  topping_2 2
  topping_3 3
  topping_4 4
```